# UPDATE Conduct proportion meta-analysis using Robumeta package -forest plot and subgroup analyses

Tags: r, meta-analysis

UPDATE: Thanks again for everyone's comments on my question and it seems like the meta-analysis is now working finally after creating a separate column on variance.

The robumeta package has now returned a pooled estimate and I was trying to generate a forest plot using the forest.robu command [image]

However, the forest plot seems a bit off and it doesn't provide a forest plot that the metafor package would generate (e.g., with events, total, and proportion of each study). What might have gone wrong here?

I also have one last question on how to use robumeta package to conduct subgroup analyses..any advice would be greatly appreciate it. Thanks very much (apologies in advance if the questions are stupid as I'm feeling a bit lost and this is my first prevalence meta-analyses)..

-
Original post

I'm conducting a meta analysis on the prevalence of violence against women. I've decided to use Robumeta package given that some the studies reported multiple prevalence estimates and some reported a single one. This is the code that I entered:

```
test.prevalence <- robu(formula = Prevalence ~ 1, data = Any_VAC_280823_adjusted,
                         studynum = Study_Number, var.eff.size = Prevalence,
                         rho = .8, small = TRUE)
test.prevalence
```

Here is the result

```
RVE: Correlated Effects Model with Small-Sample Corrections 

Model: Prevalence ~ 1 

Number of studies = 17 
Number of outcomes = 119 (min = 1 , mean = 7 , median = 4 , max = 35 )
Rho = 0.8 
I.sq = 96.63744 
Tau.sq = 135.325 

               Estimate StdErr t-value  dfs  P(|t|>) 95% CI.L 95% CI.U Sig
1 X.Intercept.     20.7   4.81    4.29 15.7 0.000582     10.4     30.9 ***
---
Signif. codes: < .01 *** < .05 ** < .10 *
---
Note: If df < 4, do not trust the results
```

I have a hard time understanding the overall prevalence here, given the result, does it mean the pooled prevalence estimate is 20.7% (95% 10.4-30.9)? The CI values also seem a bit off...

Just a note that I included the raw percentage data under var.eff.size.

Any guidance would be greatly appreciated! Please also suggest any readings. I've read Fisher and Tipton's paper on this package. Thanks!

Comment: Are the `Prevalence` values proportions or percentages? And `var.eff.size = Prevalence` makes no sense -- the sampling variance of a proportion (or percentage) is not the proportion (or percentage) itself. Also, when a study reports multiple prevalences, are those always based on the same sample or also at times on different samples? Those are two different scenarios that lead to different types of dependencies which should be reflected in the analysis (in the former case, the sampling errors are correlated, but not in the latter case).

Comment: Hi Wolfgang thank you so much for your comment. the prevalence values are percentages. For your second question, the multiple prevalences are based on the sample sample (measuring different violence types).

Comment: You do need the proper variances for the percentages for this to make any sense (as @Wolfgang remarked). If you fix that your puzzle may be solved. Perhaps.

Comment: Hi @mdewey thanks a lot for your comment. I've created a new column in the data extraction sheet to calculate the variances and now it's working.