# Creating forest plot and conducting subgroup analysis using robumeta

Tags: r, data-visualization, meta-analysis

Thanks again for everyone's comments on my previous post [UPDATE Conduct proportion meta-analysis using Robumeta package -forest plot and subgroup analyses](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/625133/update-conduct-proportion-meta-analysis-using-robumeta-package-forest-plot-and) and it seems like the proportion meta-analysis is now working finally after creating a separate column on variance.

The robumeta package has now returned a pooled estimate and I was trying to generate a forest plot using the forest.robu command forest.robu(vac.prevalence.final, es.lab = "Prevalence", study.lab = "Authors")
[image]

However, the forest plot seems a bit off and it doesn't provide a forest plot that the metafor package would generate (e.g., with events, total, and proportion of each study). What might have gone wrong here?

I also have one last question on how to use robumeta package to conduct subgroup analyses..any advice would be greatly appreciate it. Thanks very much (apologies in advance if the questions are stupid as I'm feeling a bit lost and this is my first prevalence meta-analyses)..